# Entity Framework Core Incompatibility of int[].Any(...)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

#### Situation

I am currently facing a situation in which i migrated from .Net Framework to .Net Core and with the change, also to Entity Framework Core 5.0

I have tons of spots in my code, that use Entity Framework like follows:

```
int[] groupids = ...;

IQueryable<User> query = dbContext.Users;

if (groupids.Any())
{
    // ParentFK is int?
    query = query.Where((it) => groupids.Any((id) => it.ParentFK == id)); 
}
```

the actual code in `Any(Func<...>)` may be more complex too, so replacing it with `Contains(...)` is not really an option for every possible spot.

The change is also not listed on the possibel incompatibilities list which makes the situation kinda a surprise to me too.

#### Question

Why was this dropped? Is there some easy way to reintegrate it?

#### Actual error message

> System.InvalidOperationException:
> 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(p => __groupids_1
> .Any(id => p.ParentFK == (Nullable)id))' could not be translated.
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
> See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

Comment: How does this incompatibility manifest itself?

Comment: What about making `groupids` a `int?[]`? (if this is the problem)

Comment: The query.Where() is something wild that captures its body, and I wonder if what you've got in .Any() is too complex to compile to SQL.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Progman This is essentially the Minimal reproducible example. Unless you expect me to provide the "class network" required to actually run the Entity Framework Core, making it more of an example of how to use Entity Framework.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Added actual error message of the exception raised.

Comment: Try `groupids.Contains(it.ParentFK)` what you have ought to work however.

Comment: @Joshua Coming from Entity Framework, this worked fine prior and compiled (in this case at least) to the same code as `Contains` did, which is why it was decided to use LINQ `Any()` over `array.Contains()`, simply to avoid having someone randomly encounter that incompatibility. Other spots involve executing eg. (EF6) `query.Where((q) => likeStrings.Any((likeExpression) => DbFunction.Like(likeExpression, query)))`, expanding to valid SQL

Comment: While that is an option for `groupids` @AluanHaddad , a lot of spots in the code are not as "simple" to alter as here. Updated the question to contain further info about the real question as that was not present prior. Thanks for the input anyways :)

Comment: @X39: The error message is telling you how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to execute this query on the server-side. **EF** generates a warning about this, but execute this condition on the client-side, and that's why it works.
But **EFCore** generates an error and you should explicitly execute the translatable part of the query and then execute LINQ to objects part of the query on client-side

```
int[] groupids = ...;

IQueryable<User> query = dbContext.Users;

if (groupids.Any())
{
    var partialResult = query.ToArray(); // get data from DB
    
    // and filter on client side
    var result = partialResult.Where((it) => groupids.Any((id) => it.ParentFK == id)); 
}
```

**NOTE** For situations where: *the actual code in Any(Func<...>) may be more complex too, so replacing it with Contains(...) is not really an option for every possible spot*